# mediaelement.js context menu

Tags: contextmenu, mediaelement.js

Could anyone point me to the code snippet where I can find the usage of context menu for mediaelement.js?

I am looking to disable the context menu that pops up when I do right click on the video and also to add/delete context menu elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the items which are displayed in the context menu by editing the method `renderContextMenu` in the file `mediaelementplayer.js`
Setting as follows will prevent any menu items from appearing:

```js
var t = this,
html = '',
items=''; --> no menu items
```